# ndk-build: undefined reference to .. errors when statically linking to libxml.a

Tags: android, android-ndk

I get a lot of undefined reference to ... errors when I compile my single c++ source-file using the ndk-build tool. For the record I use NDK r6 on a linux host system.

First of all I've been banging my head against this problem all day, so I am sorry if I am leaving something out or explaining myself a bit fast. Please ask me for any additional information.

My source-code has a lot of dependent libraries that I want to statically link to.
I have defined all my dependent libs of different  in my Android.mk file as follows:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := <name>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib<name>.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := <header files related to this lib>

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

While I make sure that these are available in my jni/ folder as lib.a with my Android.mk and Application.mk files. (and my source file)
Also I've added STL support by adding `APP_STL := stlport_static` to my Application.mk file.
My single source file (riidr-jni.cpp) is at the moment:

```
#include <string>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "../com_riidr_apps_reader_RiidrEbookReaderActivity.h"
#include <dp_all.h>

void Java_com_riidr_apps_reader_RiidrEbookReaderActivity_init ( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz ) {
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Riidr", "JNI init - start");
    dp::platformInit( dp::PI_DEFAULT );
}
```

If I uncomment the `dp::platformInit( dp::PI_DEFAULT );` line and replace it with `std::string test = "asd";` I have no errors at all, this makes me believe that the  and therefore STL lib is correctly imported and linked.

The last instructions of my Android.mk file is this

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := riidr-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := riidr-jni.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl -lz
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  \
hobbes \
dp \
adept \
mschema \
hobbes \
t3 \
xml \
mschema \
dp \
adept \
xml \
cryptopenssl \
fonts \
png \
jpeg \
ssl \
crypto \
expat \
cts \
hyphen \
curl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error I get when running the ndk-build tool is the following:

> /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator++()':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt17_Rb_tree_iteratorISt4pairIKN3uft5ValueEPN5xpath14DynamicContextEEEppEv[std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator++()]+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIN3uft5ValueESt4pairIKS1_PN5xpath14DynamicContextEESt10_Select1stIS7_ENS4_7Context12ValueCompareESaIS7_EE5eraseESt17_Rb_tree_iteratorIS7_E[std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >)]+0x28): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> const&)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeIN3uft5ValueESt4pairIKS1_PN5xpath14DynamicContextEESt10_Select1stIS7_ENS4_7Context12ValueCompareESaIS7_EE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS7_[std::_Rb_tree<uft::Value, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >, xpath::Context::ValueCompare, std::allocator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> const&)]+0xc4): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator--()':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt23_Rb_tree_const_iteratorISt4pairIKN3uft5ValueEPN5xpath14DynamicContextEEEmmEv[std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator--()]+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator++()':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt23_Rb_tree_const_iteratorISt4pairIKN3uft5ValueEPN5xpath14DynamicContextEEEppEv[std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator++()]+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<mdom::Node*>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIPN4mdom4NodeEE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<mdom::Node*>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x4c): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<mdom::Node>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4mdom4NodeEE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<mdom::Node>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x4c): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator--()':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt17_Rb_tree_iteratorISt4pairIKN3uft5ValueEPN5xpath14DynamicContextEEEmmEv[std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> >::operator--()]+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_front(unsigned int)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5dequeIN4mdom4NodeESaIS1_EE24_M_new_elements_at_frontEj[std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_front(unsigned int)]+0x58): undefined reference to`std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_back(unsigned int)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZNSt5dequeIN4mdom4NodeESaIS1_EE23_M_new_elements_at_backEj[std::deque<mdom::Node, std::allocator<mdom::Node> >::_M_new_elements_at_back(unsigned int)]+0x58): undefined reference to`std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_context.o): In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
>   xpath_context.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt13_Rb_tree_nodeISt4pairIKN3uft5ValueEPN5xpath14DynamicContextEEEE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<uft::Value const, xpath::DynamicContext*> > >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x4c): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_yacc.o): In function `std::list<uft::Value*, std::allocator<uft::Value*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<uft::Value*>, uft::Value* const&)':
>   xpath_yacc.cpp:(.text._ZNSt4listIPN3uft5ValueESaIS2_EE9_M_insertESt14_List_iteratorIS2_ERKS2_[std::list<uft::Value*, std::allocator<uft::Value*> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<uft::Value*>, uft::Value* const&)]+0x3c): undefined reference to`std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)'
>   /home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libxml.a(xpath_yacc.o): In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<uft::Value*> >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
>   xpath_yacc.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIPN3uft5ValueEEE8allocateEjPKv[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<uft::Value*> >::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x4c): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [/home/creen/Projects/Riidr/workspace/RiidrEbookReader/obj/local/armeabi/libriidr-jni.so] Error 1

Any info, questions or anything really is highly appreciated.

Comment: The project was halted - I could not get any of the answers to solve my actual problem. But thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 32):

Add the line

```
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
```

to the Android.mk file and it should work. 
As explained in the ndk doc, it is because the ndk performs a debug checking even for avoiding runtime linking error and for some motivations it doesn't find the correct references in a pre-built library. Hope it coulds help.

Comment: Although using LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SUMBOLS := true will get the code to compile, it may result in the program not running. It will cause a library not found error at run time. Unless you are sure this is what you want I would recomend only using it if you are sure the shared library with the symbols will be installed on the device.

Answer (score 3):

You had to add `APP_STL := stlport_static` to the `Application.mk` file, not `Android.mk`.

**EDIT**: As far as I can see you haven't linked against stlport static library. So I think you should add something like `-lstlport` to `LOCAL_LDLIBS`.

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad. I ment Application.mk. I have edited my post now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As others had mentioned,

LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

will not work at run time. Have a look at this:

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

I ran into the same problem with boost (I use a custom 1.42 version).

Using the brute force method to configure gnustdc++ fixed my issue. The important thing is to link against -lgnustl_static (or whatever stl lib you use) after your libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some functionalities are enabled by default while they may need some extra linking to other libraries , this functionalities are : 
- support loading MOD music via modplug .
- support loading MOD music via mikmod
- support loading MP3 music via SMPEG
you should disable these options to build sdl2_mixer so go to "Android.mk" ( of SDL2_mixer) file and you will find :

```
SUPPORT_MOD_MODPLUG ?= true
...
SUPPORT_MOD_MIKMOD ?= true
...
SUPPORT_MP3_SMPEG ?= true
```

change those to "false" and it will work for you as did with me !

**NOTES :**

```
 LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
```

**1- will cause a runtime error , because the symbol will still not be resolved at runtime**

**2- You won't be able to load mp3 files but you can covert them to "ogg" with almost the same size and quality , but you can find the perfect solution of your exact problem here [Runtime linking error with SDL_Mixer and SMPEG2 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093953/runtime-linking-error-with-sdl-mixer-and-smpeg2-on-android/28094163#28094163)**

Answer (score -1):

Do you looked at the bug #16627 ?

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16627

I'm running ndk-r8, but I'm still having those errors though.

Comment: The project was halted, but no I didn't at the moment. But thanks anyway :)